# Not able to play sound in electron app after packaging

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, electron

I have created an electron app consisting a sound effect. I am using the package `sound-play` to play the sound effect in my `main.js` file (learned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60601215/playing-audio-in-electron-from-main-process)). It is working as it should when I am running it through `npm start`. But after packaging  my app using `electron-packager`, when I am running the exe file from "release-builds" folder, only the sound effect is not playing. All other aspects of the app are working fine.

Shutter.mp3 is the sound file which is present in the project directory

Main.js:

```
const sound = require("sound-play");
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "shutter.mp3");
sound.play(filePath)  //For playing the sound inside a function
```

Package.json:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . Namegoeshere --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"Namegoeshere\"",
    "package-linux": "electron-packager . electron-tutorial-app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/png/1024x1024.png --prune=true --out=release-builds"
  },
```

Using the command `npm package-win` for packaging.

*Just pointing it out again only sound is not playing after packaging. Other aspects are totally fine.*

I am probably missing something very basic. Any help would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: Without some code, it's hard to help you. Are you loading the sound file using `__dirname` in the path and have you disabled ASAR when packaging?

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner My bad. I have added some of the code that you mentioned. Take a look now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Similar to the electron-builder solution I listed below, I searched the electron-packager doc and found a similar option for extra files, instead of "files" you will use "extraResource", check it out [in the docs](https://electron.github.io/electron-packager/main/interfaces/electronpackager.options.html#extraresource).

Original answer:

If you are using webpack to bundle your app before packaging, see if you can include it in your Javascript file and have a file loader in your webpack explained [here(blog site)](https://tomroth.com.au/react-sound/),  [here (Stack overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38252453/serving-mp3-files-using-the-webpack-file-loader), and of course [here (webpack official)](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) .
Be sure to install File-loader!

I prefer to use [Electron builder](https://www.electron.build/) for packaging apps, if you were to switch, you could include the file into your packaged app as follows:

List the audio file in your JSON settings (package.json) to be included in your packager e.g.:

```
"build": {
    // ...Other settings go here,
    "files": [
      "path/to/sound.mp3" //<-- This will include the file separately 
      // into your app's build
   ]
}
```

You can then use a relative path in your app, but if you don't have a similar path in your development build things might get iffy. You can find out more about the electron-builder packaging options [on their website](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration#MetadataDirectories-app). IMO the bundler (webpack) solution would be best. Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much. "extraResource" came in handy. Sorry for being late in accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use base64 data instead of sound file path. Also in renderer process with HTML5 Audio:

```js
import soundBase64Data from '../path/to/sound.mp3'

new Audio(soundBase64Data).play() // this line for renderer process only
```